# How to get selected value and displaying values in dropdwon from database - Codeigniter 3

Tags: model-view-controller, codeigniter-3, dropdown

I'm setting up edit form using Codeigniter 3 + Bootstrap where has value form selected before and want to displaying values dynamically in dropdown select box. Where my code goes wrong?

I created edit view and have dropdown where fetching selected values from database, i'm able to fetching the value from db but i can't displaying the list values in dropdown so user can edit his choice. 
Error i got : **Undefined variable : city**

```
//Controller
$data['detail'] = $this->profile_model->show(); //get data based id
$data1['city'] = $this->profile_model->getCity(); //to display value in dropdown
$this->load->view('v_update_user', $data, $data1);

//View

 <form class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo base_url().'users/update'?>">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>                         
        <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="input-group">                          
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo $row->name?>">
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
       <div class="col-sm-4">
        <select class="form-control" name="kota" id="city" name="kota">                       
         <option value="" selected><?php echo $row->cityname?></option>
         <?php foreach($city as $row) { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $row->citycode?>"><?php echo $row->cityname?> 
         </option>
        <?php } ?>
        </select>
        </div>
```

I expect the output can display the values from selected before and displaying the list values as well in dropdown select box

Answer (score 0):

Try to combine the `$data` array like this :

```
$data['detail'] = $this->profile_model->show(); //get data based id
$data['city'] = $this->profile_model->getCity(); //to display value in dropdown
$this->load->view('v_update_user', $data);
```

Comment: If i combine the $data, i've got error **A PHP Error was encountered, Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$name**. Basically the $data['detail'] won't pass the value based on selected id. What should i do?

Comment: In input type text at form edit, each field has values based on selected id from $data['detail'], i update the view to give you some insight.

Comment: Could you show the rest of the html form so we have a figure of the looping structure

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to solved this by add foreach in each field dropdown.. thanks @HastaDhana for taking your times to answer my question :)